# See when someone was last online. Skype For Business

Tags: skype, skype-for-business

On skype most the time I can see when someone was last online, as their status will say `Offline 14 hours`

However this morning I went to see if a certain person was in work, and if not when were they last online, however it just tells me they are offline. I could see their offline status last week.

See image below.

Why does it show for some when they were last online, but not others ? and is there a way for me to see the others last online point ?

[image]

I can see Taylor was online 25 mins ago, but not Powell.

*My thinking is, perhaps the person that is just showing offline, is maybe online, and has set to shows as offline, and therefore skype cannot give a time they have been offline ?*

Comment: The server they're connected to might not publish that information. That would depend on your Skype for Business deployment. This might also be influenced by the relationship that contact set you to. In the end it doesn't really matter. Either call or send a mail.

Comment: @Seth I only need to know if they have been online or not, thanks for the point about server. If they had logged on via a VPN would that make any difference ? if they were in work they would be on the same server as Taylor in my pic. but they may have logged on at home via a VPN.

Comment: The information is kept on the server and published by it. I'm not sure how it would be handled if it is a Skype for Business Online deployment. You could probably dig into the back end Database to find that information if you have that access and it's important.

Comment: "issues specific to corporate IT support and networks" are off-topic here as per https://superuser.com/help/on-topic